# Someone could help, why this does not read a file?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

```
;------------------------------------------------------
Pila Segment

    db 0FFFFh Dup (?) ;declracion del segmento de pila

Pila EndS
;------------------------------------------------------

;------------------------------------------------
Datos Segment ; declaracion del segmento de datos

    archivo db 0;,0;?
    leido db 81 dup (24h) ; Cantidad de letras que va a leer.
    handle dw ? ; Identificador para el archivo.

Datos ENdS
;------------------------------------------------

;----------------------------------------------------
Codigo Segment ; declaracion del segmento de codigo

Assume CS:Codigo, DS:Datos, SS:Pila

Inicio:

    mov ax, Datos
    mov DS, ax
    xor ax,ax 


    mov ah,01h  
    int 21h

    mov archivo, al
    mov dx, offset archivo ;

    mov al, 0h 
    mov dx, offset archivo 
    mov ah, 3dh 
    int 21h 
    mov handle, ax 
    mov bx, handle
    mov cx, 79h 
    mov dx, offset leido 
    mov ah, 3fh
    int 21h


    mov bx, handle
    mov ah, 3eh
    int 21h

    xor ax,ax 
    xor dx,dx
     ;imprimir el contenido de leido
    mov dx, offset leido ;
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    xor ax,ax ;Limpia el al y prepara el ah para la salida.
    mov ax,4c00h ;Servicio AH=4c int 21h para salir del programa.
    int 21h ;Termina el programa.

Codigo EndS
    End Inicio
```

Comment: To help attract more potential answers, please translate what you can into English.

Comment: And format your code so it is legible.

Comment: Your code seems to assume that every interrupt it triggers will succeed. Don't do that. Consult the documentation for the interrupts that you're using and add adequate error handling to your code.

Comment: @GuilinNEX If you don't check for any errors from the DOS calls, then at the very least make sure that the current directory indeed contains the file (with a single character filename!) that you want to read.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> archivo db 0;,0;?
> ```

The way you're using *archivo* suggests that you are inputting from the keyboard a single character filename. This is fine provided you setup the *archivo* buffer in the correct way:

```
archivo db 0,0
```

---

> ```
> mov bx, handle
> mov cx, 79h 
> mov dx, offset leido 
> mov ah, 3fh
> int 21h
> ```

Here you need to pay attention to the number system that you use! You've asked for a size (in `CX`) of 79 **h** (an hexadecimal number) which is much more than the 81 bytes buffer at *leido*.
You probably wanted to write:

```
mov cx, 79       ;Without the "h"
```

---

> ```
> db 0FFFFh Dup (?) ;declracion del segmento de pila
> ```

The rest of the program should pose no problems, except I dislike the way you've setup the stack. You should always exclusively setup an **even sized** stack and in this small program it need not be that big at all:

```
db 512 dup (?) ;declracion del segmento de pila
```

An easy way to get the even size right is by using the `dw` directive.
The same 512 bytes stack then becomes:

```
dw 256 dup (?) ;declracion del segmento de pila
```

Comment: @GuilinNEX If you don't check for any errors from the DOS calls, then at the very least make sure that the current directory indeed contains the file (with a single character filename!) that you want to read.